# MongoDB - weird find behavior on embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection in my `test` database.

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:45:48.338 >>> db.blog.posts.find( );
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52ee29bdb8eb94049427886a"),
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "author" : "Jane",
                        "comment" : "yes, yes, it is",
                        "votes" : 5
                }
        ],
        "content" : "This is a post",
        "id" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52f95c5bd1fe9c171fe4344b"),
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "author" : "Jane",
                        "comment" : "yes, yes, it is",
                        "votes" : 5
                },
                {
                        "author" : "Nick",
                        "comment" : "test",
                        "votes" : 10
                },
                {
                        "author" : "John",
                        "comment" : "new one",
                        "votes" : 4
                }
        ],
        "content" : "This is a post",
        "id" : 5
}
```

When I run this find query:

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:45:50.318 >>> db.blog.posts.find({ "comments" : {author : "Jane", comment: "yes, yes, it is", votes: 5}} );
```

I get both documents back.

But if I run this find query

```
[test] 2014-02-11 18:46:18.428 >>> db.blog.posts.find({ "comments" : {author : "Jane", comment: "yes, yes, it is", votes: {$gte : 5}}} );
```

I get no documents back.

Why is that? How come == 5 gives me results back but >= 5 does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting case, to be honest. But, I think there
are more efficient commands to get what you need.

I have solved your issue as follows.

```
db.posts.find({
 "comments": {
    "$elemMatch": {
       author : "Jane", 
       comment: "yes, yes, it is", 
       votes: {"$gte" : 5}
    }
  }
});
```

and the result is as follows:

[image]

*The reason the first OP query works and the second OP query doesn't is because

in the first case there are documents that meet the exact form being queried.

The second OP query uses a modifier, hence the need to wrap with $elemMatch.*

More information from the official MongoDB site can be found here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very good. Perhaps it would help to explain the reason the first query worked and the second one didn't was because in the first case there were s documents that met the *exact* form being queried. The second case uses a *modifier*, hence the need to wrap with **$elemMatch**